# iCloud Sync Button inside the app reject

Tags: iphone, icloud

Apple reject the app if put the Sync iCloud button inside the app. Any other way to do that thing.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Since iCloud doesn't work that way, what did that button do? You can't tell iCloud when to sync.

Comment: HI thanks for your reply Tom. I understand, Is that possible  can we set Enable or Disable iCloud Sync. ?

Comment: @TomHarrington HI need Sync On/Off from end user side. If user dont want to sync then its not backup in icloud. What is the best thing for me ? Also now i will take a backup on every 30 Second , when user On icloud Sync. Is that possible  ? apple allow that ? Any limit of backup every minute or Second ?

Comment: It sounds like you are very unfamiliar with how iCloud works. Apple provides extensive documentation on how and when to use iCloud in apps. I suggest becoming at least a little bit familiar with iCloud first, and coming back to this site if you have some more specific questions.

Comment: @TomHarrington Thanks for your reply, But i did not understand with that Documents, So i ask some Question to you.. Sorry if i disturb you, and please its great if you provide some information..Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need a button inside your app? iCloud syncs everything in your app's documents folder into the cloud when it backs up (determined by the iOS)  , of course, if your app is selected to be backed up in the iCloud settings.

I think that's the reason they rejected your app, because the sync button in unnecessary.

Comment: HI.. thanks for your reply.. As per application Requirement, i set iCloud and Dropbox..Both button . i need Sync when user can press on that button not before that.

Comment: Even if you could trigger an iCloud back up from your app, it doesn't work like that. It syncs everything, from all the apps + contacts+ photos. Dropbox is straight foward...you have files..you send them to dropbox..end of story. From what i know , in ios 6 and up (i'm 100% sure on ios 7) iCloud only syncs when the device is connected to wifi, and locked or when is connected to iTunes. It's am os driven feature. It wont sync if you're on cellular network ( or at least it doesn't for me). So yea...having a button in your app that could start sync is a no-no, not that you could.

Comment: HI Thanks for your reply, I like to set Enable or Disable iCloud sync in side the app. Is that possible ?

Comment: Waiting for your reply

Comment: i'm sorry but i kinda sorta forgot :) . I think [this]( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: hi.. Thanks for your reply. Yes i also take the Same as Backup when user Enable iCloud Backup inside the App. I put one button to provide Enabled & Disable. My question is that when enabled then when i will take backup, mean after every 30 Sec or 1 Min. Because my whole app concern with Local Database and each small event in the app, effect to database.So let me provide the better Suggestion. Also apple allow that Enable or Disable or not ? Awaiting for your kind response,Thanks

Comment: they allow enable and disable of certain files in your Documents directory. As i said before, you cannot control when the backup will take place. A better solution would be to make your own server and when the user does something in your app..you can send the info to your server. That way you have full control over what and when it backs up.

Comment: HI..Yes i understand but requirement of client on iCloud.See what i can do  : i make the Document with my App name on icloud. Crete first Document and open it every time. When any data insert or update or delete in Database , i can Sync icloud backup on Every 30 Sec... Is this right way or not ?

Comment: NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]
                                URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];
    
    Note *doc = [[Note alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    doc.noteContent = data;
    
    [doc saveToURL:[doc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        
  if (success) {}else{}  This the code time of backup..